# Change the status of orders automatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I need to change the status of my orders to (Cancelled) automatically after 7 days if it is not processed.

I need to change the status from: New Request to Cancelled.
Or
I need to change the status from: Processing to Cancelled.

Thanks
Adnan

Comment: You will need server cron job not wp cron to achive this. WP cron works only if someone is visiting your website so i would avoid using it. Then grab all orders with desired statuses and update.

Comment: I have a server cron job on my server but I still need to add the php code to my WP to automate the cancellation of the orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did that with the help of this code:

```
function autocancel_wc_orders(){
    $query = ( array(
        'limit'   => 10,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'status'  => array( 'wc-pending', 'wc-ywraq-new', 'wc-ywraq- 
        pending')
    ) );
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $query );
    foreach( $orders as $order ){       

        $date     = new DateTime( $order->get_date_created() );
        $today    = new DateTime();
        $interval = $date->diff($today);

        $datediff = $interval->format('%a');

        if( $datediff > 2 ){
            $order->update_status('cancelled', 'Cancelled for missing 
            payment');
        }   
    }
} 
add_action( 'admin_init', 'autocancel_wc_orders' );
```

I found this answer online in the link:
https://samuelsilva.pt/cancel-woocommerce-not-paid-orders-automatically/

Answer (score 0):

Helpful documentation - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters
https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_order_statuses/

```
//My server cronjob is targeting wp-cron.php 
function ss_cancel_failed_orders() {
    $held_duration = 15; //minutes how often my cron job to run per day/hour
    $data_store = WC_Data_Store::load('order');

    //Change post_status for desired order statuses
    //Change date_query before value to desired time compare with modified post date
    $unpaid_orders = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'shop_order', 'post_status' => array('wc-failed','wc-on-hold'), 'date_query' => array(array('before' => '15 minutes ago', 'column'=>'post_modified' ))));
    if ( $unpaid_orders ) {
        foreach ( $unpaid_orders as $unpaid_order ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $unpaid_order );
            $order->update_status( 'cancelled', __( 'Order has expired.', 'woocommerce' ) ); // Status here is without wc- prefix
        }
    }
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'ssa_cancel_failed_orders' );
    wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 ), 'ssa_cancel_failed_orders' ); // you can remove wp cron and work with server cron only
  }
  add_action('ssa_cancel_failed_orders', 'ss_cancel_failed_orders');
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested but seems does not work. My cron job runs every 5 minutes. I tested with order status wp-pending. 

One more question, array('wc-failed','wc-on-hold') is this mean wc-failed or wc-on-hold?

Comment: Use - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/ to check what is happening. Means grab orders with statuses wc-failed and wc-on-hold.

Comment: Nothing happening even when I run the event manually using the wp-control plugin.

Comment: Do you get any orders ?

Comment: I have hundreds of orders. But the code do not update the status.

Comment: Do you get any orders in current loop?